# SQL Server : how to delete a row number

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, database

[image: Table itself]

I have a SQL Server table (as shown above) and I am ordering it in a table on my website by using this command

```
SELECT * 
FROM [user]  
ORDER BY idNum DESC;
```

This table (running on my website) has all the information my database holds (at least for the [user] table)

I have buttons to delete a row off the information (it gets the row number that I want to delete), as shown in this screenshot:

[image: Table on my website]

What I want to ask is there a way to delete a row using a row number?(Cause I get a row number off the button click I just want to delete that row)?

Comment: Don't use a "row number" or anything like that to delete your rows - use the **primary key** that's there to **uniquely and reliably** identify each row

Comment: @marc_s I was going to advise exactly the same. Using rownumber can actually result in removing the wrong entry because your table data may change between looking at it and deleting the row you want.

Comment: Why don't you add a real row number, and use it as primary key. It will make your life easier...

Comment: @ppijnenburg But a primary key could also disappear.  I vote for deleting via primary key but this could be made to work with certain assumptions.

Comment: if you try to delete the PK that is already gone you get represented with an error. If you delete a specific rownumber, good chance the rownumber will still be there given that the amount of rows exceed the current row you want to delete.

Comment: Always use the primary key. When you get the data to populate the table, the row 2 can be, for instance, "John" and, in meantime while you're trying to delete the row, a new row can be added,  so the row 2 could be other than "John", bad idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
DELETE FROM USER
WHERE idnum IN (SELECT idnum from (SELECT idnum,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 
idnum desc) AS rw FROM USER) res WHERE res.rw = @rw)
```

`@rw` is your row number

Answer (score 2):

You could use a CTE here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY idNum DESC) rn
    FROM [user]
)
```

Then delete using a row number, coming from the UI:

```
DELETE
FROM cte
WHERE rn = <some value from UI>;
```

But many (most?) UI frameworks, e.g. Angular, would have the ability to send the entire metadata for a user to the UI.  So, you would typically be able to delete just using the `idNum` value coming directly from the button in the UI.  As @marc_s just commented, deleting using the primary key is a safe way to do deletions.

Comment: Technically possible but it's not a good idea to expose your internal ID to the browser.

Comment: @TheImpaler I see nothing wrong whatsoever with exposing a primary key value.  App security does the job of making sure that requests only come from valid sources.

Comment: Even if it comes from the right IP, you may not be dealing with a browser but a different user-agent. You may end up deleting a row from another user.

Comment: @TheImpaler I don't know what sort of applications you develop, but this problem was solved a long time ago.  Typically a user must present an auth token in each request.  Only deletions from rows which he owns would be allowed, so even if a malicious user were to hack, he still could never delete someone else's data.

Answer (score 0):

Your method of using `row_number()` is simply wrong.  It is not thread-safe -- another user could be added into the database, throwing off all the "row numbers" that you have shown to users.  Gosh, a user to load a page and keep the app open for a week, and a bunch of new users could have added or removed before the user gets around to deleting something.

Fundamentally, you have a malformed table.  It doesn't have a primary key or even any unique constraints.

I would strongly advise:

```
create table Users (
    userId int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    . . .
);
```

This is the primary key that you should be using for deletion.  You don't need to show the primary key to the user, as long as you can associate it with each row.

Primary keys are important for other reasons.  In general, one uses databases because to store more than one table.  The primary key is how you connect the different tables to each other (using foreign key relationships).